# How to share a common argument between nested function calls in Python?

Tags: python

I have two Python functions `f()` and `g()` which share one argument: `a`.

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

def g(a, c):
    return a * c
```

Sometimes, `g()` is called standalone, in which case both arguments are necessary:

```py
g(a = 1, c = 3)
```

Sometimes, `g()` is called as an argument inside a `f()` call:

```py
f(a = 1, b = g(a = 1, c = 3))
```

Notice that that the `a` argument is redundant, because it always has to have the same value in `f()` and `g()`. I would like to avoid this repetition.

`g()` should figure out if it is called inside a `f()` call. If so, and if the `a` argument is not explicitly provided, then it should use the same `a` argument specified in the `f()` call. In other words, I want the same result as above with this simpler call:

```py
f(a = 1, g(c = 3))
```

Comment: In my real application, there are exactly two optional/shared arguments. If an argument is not shared and appears only in g() --- like c in the current case--- then it is not optional and does not require any special treatment.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to create a third function `k` which takes all the arguments and calls the `f` and `g` functions correctly.

Comment: There is no way for `g()` to figure out if it is called as `g(1, 3)` or `f(1, g(1, 3))` because in both the cases `g()` is called outside of `f()` and the `return` value of `g()` is passed to `f()` as a parameter

Comment: Are you sure? I was hoping there would be a solution with the `inspect` module or something like it. But I'm admittedly out of my depth there.

Comment: You can do it using `inspect.getouterframes()`. The question is why would you do that? If it is merely to avoid writing the parameters twice. I would say don't do it. Because you just changed how the language syntax works, thus confusing everyone who reads your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm aware of the tradeoff, and you're right I would never use this internally. But this is a top level function, and a very common pattern, so it would save users lots of keystrokes. Nevertheless, you objections is well notes.

Comment: If this is top-level and you want to save keystrokes. I would suggest you look into creating a DSL rather than bending Python syntax itself. That way you know what operations the user of your library can perform. Using things like `inspect` to achieve what you are trying to do is a bad idea because your contract becomes as wide as the language itself and as Python syntax evolves you will have to continuously maintain the library and fix bugs in your library introduced due edge cases in the language design that you were unaware of.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible, `g` cannot know how it is called and it is evaluated before `f`.

If you can modify the functions, `g` could return a partial if `a` is missing, then `f` can evaluate it if `b` is a function:

```
from functools import partial

def f(a, b):
    if callable(b):
        b = b(a)
    return a + b

def g(a=None, c=None):
    if a is None:
        return partial(g, c=c)
    return a * c

f(a = 1, b = g(a = 1, c = 3))
# 4

f(a = 1, b = g(c = 3))
# 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define `f` to take three arguments, `a`, `b`, and `c`.  If `a` and `b` are defined, return `a + b`, else return `a + g(a, c)`

```
def f(a, b=None, c=None):
    if b is None and c is None:
        raise ValueError("Either b or c are required")
    elif c is None:
        return a + b
    else:
        return a + g(a, c)
```

Call this like:

```
f(a=10, b=11) # 21

f(a=10, c=11) # 120
```

You can force them to be passed as keyword-only arguments by putting a `*` before the arguments in the definition:

```
def f(*, a, b=None, c=None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! Yes, I thought about this easy solution. But what if I'm not looking for easy and want a solution to the problem as stated? f() and g() are functions that are already exposed to users, so I cnat make many changes, and I don't want to "pollute" the interface by adding more arguments (often g() is not used at all, only case the extra argument is useless).

Comment: @Vincent Then the best way that I can think of would be to define another function that does this, like Ajinkya said. Unfortunately, when you call `f(a=1, b=g(a=1, c=2))`, the `g` function is called _before_ the `f` function is, so there's no way for `g` to know that it was called in preparation for a `f` call